# R: create text input panel and process it in a function

Tags: r

I'd like to parse pieces of text to pull out certain lines using R and I wrote a function for this purpose. The function is fine but so far I have to use readLines() to read a .txt file and then process it using my function.
However, ideally I'd like to create a popup window consiting of a text entry box, a "do it" button and a return text box. I could then copy-paste the text in a text-entry box, press the "do it" button (to send it to my funtion) and get the desired lines in the text box.
I played around with the rpanel package and its rp.textentry and rp.text functions but I'm having some problems understanding how the whole package works...

I would be grateful if you have suggestions how to make such a popup window with rpanel or any other package in R. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a package called svDialogs. The following is the link to the documentation:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/svDialogs/svDialogs.pdf
There is a function called dlgInput.

This is the simplest way to create widgets. Otherwise, my recommended solution is to use tcltk2 package.

Then:

```
library(tcltk)
tt<-toplevel(width=100,height=100)

submit<-function(){
  print(tkget(input.text,"0.0","end"))
  tkdestroy(tt)
}

input.text<-tktext(tt,width=100)
submit.bt<-tkbutton(tt,text="submit",command=submit)

tkpack(input.text, submit.bt)
```

Comment: Also check out this documentation: http://mcu.edu.tw/~chenmh/teaching/project/r/reference/R_Tcl_Tk_2001_3.pdf. tcltk is very easy to use.

Comment: Awesome - I tried svDialogs and I got it to do the job already! I will also check out tcltk! Thanks!